# How to navigate through a function React Native

Tags: react-native

trying to navigate to a screen after a function is called. The navigation works perfectly well when rendered in the component but not when the function is called and its conditions are met. I've tried passing navigation but that does not work. Why does React Navigation not work directly when outside `render()`?

```
    onSubmit = () => {
        const { base64URI } = this.props
        const { captionData } = this.state

        if (base64URI !== null && captionData !== null ) {
            console.log('post both image data and caption data as type photo')
            this.addPhoto(base64URI, captionData);
            navigate.navigation('Vault') //navigation not recognised
        } else {
            console.log('no data')
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(

                            <View style={styles.headerPost}>
                                <TouchableOpacity style={{position: 'absolute'}} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}> // this navigation works..
                                    <Text style={styles.cancelButton}>Cancel</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>

                                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.shareButton} onPress={() => this.onSubmit()}> //when this function is called and conditions met, I want navigation to happen
                                    <Text style={styles.shareText}>Share</Text>
                                </TouchableOpacity>
                            </View>
                        </View>

        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You should try formatting your code so it is easier to read, and also remove everything not related to your question. How much code can you remove, while still reproducing the problem you have?

Comment: Good point - done.

Answer (score 2):

You are using navigation in the wrong way.
it should be

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Vault')
```

Comment: Oops. That's embarassing! Thanks.